# How to select rows from Pandas dataframe after using groupby?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series, pandas-groupby

From the following data frame, how can a list of owners with more than two pets be obtained without resorting to copying/pasting or intermediate data structures?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jack', 'fuzzy',12], ['Jack', 'furry',13], ['Joe', 'scratchy',3], ['Jack', 'chirpy',40], ['Jeff', 'slithery',9], ['Jack', 'swimmy',1], ['Joe', 'feathery',14], ['Joe', 'oinky',11], ['Jack', 'stampy',1]],
                  columns=['Owner', 'Pet', 'Age'])
print(df)


  Owner       Pet  Age
0  Jack     fuzzy   12
1  Jack     furry   13
2   Joe  scratchy    3
3  Jack    chirpy   40
4  Jeff  slithery    9
5  Jack    swimmy    1
6   Joe  feathery   14
7   Joe     oinky   11
8  Jack    stampy    1
```

Getting a boolean series matching the condition is easy:

```
df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet']>2

Owner
Jack     True
Jeff    False
Joe      True
Name: Pet, dtype: bool
```

Actually distilling the matches (*Jack* and *Joe*) can be done by copying pasting the `groupby` statement:

```
df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet'][df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet']>2] 

Owner
Jack    5
Joe     3
Name: Pet, dtype: int64
```

But this is a pain if the conditional statement is long because every change needs to be repeated.  The only other way discovered so far is to throw the series back into a data frame and use `query()`, but this feel impossibly hackish:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet']).query('Pet > 2')

       Pet
Owner     
Jack     5
Joe      3
```

Is there a better way than these?

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: you mean by copying that you don't want to just assign the results to a variable and work on it instead?

Comment: @MedAli by copy/pasting I mean this string: `df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet']`

Comment: It feels like you are overthing the problem. You could just assign to another variable and work on it `df1= df.groupby('Owner').count()['Pet']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.loc` indexer with a filtering function.

```
>>> df.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().loc[lambda p: p > 2]
Owner
Jack    5
Joe     3
Name: Pet, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`compress`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.compress.html) method.

```
>>> df.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().compress(lambda p: p > 2)
Owner
Jack    5
Joe     3
Name: Pet, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Owner.values)
b = np.bincount(f)
m = b > 2
u[m]

array(['Jack', 'Joe'], dtype=object)
```

Or produce a series

```
pd.Series(b[m], u[m])

Jack    5
Joe     3
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**
use same `groupby` twice

**2.1**
Funky `lambda`

```
(lambda p: p[p > 2])(df.groupby('Owner').Pet.count())

Owner
Jack    5
Joe     3
Name: Pet, dtype: int64
```

**2.2**
`pipe`
I'd rather use @Mitch's answer than this one.

```
df.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().pipe(lambda p: p[p > 2])

Owner
Jack    5
Joe     3
Name: Pet, dtype: int64
```

---

**Timing**
*Code Below*

```
# Multiples of minimum runtime: Smaller is better.
#
       pir1      pir2      pir3      mch1      mch2
10      1.0  2.984347  2.907198  2.422435  2.736712
30      1.0  3.396997  3.464083  3.023355  3.353150
100     1.0  3.646931  3.053890  2.586377  2.859365
300     1.0  4.541890  4.037132  3.054388  3.323939
1000    1.0  2.529670  2.438109  2.214494  2.415056
3000    1.0  3.212312  3.739621  3.062538  2.969489
10000   1.0  2.923211  2.807983  2.970712  2.637492
30000   1.0  2.790350  2.830328  2.978083  2.719900
```

[image]

```
def pir1(d, c):
    f, u = pd.factorize(d.Owner.values)
    b = np.bincount(f)
    m = b > c
    return pd.Series(b[m], u[m])

pir2 = lambda d, c: (lambda p: p[p > c])(d.groupby('Owner').Pet.count())
pir3 = lambda d, c: d.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().pipe(lambda p: p[p > c])
mch1 = lambda d, c: d.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().loc[lambda p: p > c]
mch2 = lambda d, c: d.groupby('Owner').Pet.count().compress(lambda p: p > c)

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    columns='pir1 pir2 pir3 mch1 mch2'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    c = 2 * i
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d, c)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, c, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=10)

res.div(res.min(1), 0)

res.plot(loglog=True)
```